# how to use the global search in watson explorer application builder

Tags: watson, watson-explorer

I am new to IBM Watson Explorer's Application Builder component.
I able to create some widgets and place them on a page, but I am not able to figure out how to use the global search bar in the page header. 
I want to search for something using the global search and the data in the widgets on the page should be updated.
Tried reading the knowledge center docs, but not able to get much info.

Answer (score 1):

For making use of the global search, you may want to understand, where the data for that resides.

The Watson Explorer Engine is where you ingest your documents by creating a search collection and by adding them as seeds and then once that is all set up and you are able to see your data there, you can now switch over to the AppBuilder.

- Link (Creating a search collection): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8NLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.tut.auth.doc/t_vse-auth-tut-create-display.html

Tabs on admin page of AppBuilder look like this: [Image Link: AppBuilder tab header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxlG.png)

Once on AppBuilder admin dashboard, you might want to create a new entity by going to the **entity tab**, located at the top of the page.
Then you can name it whatever you like and from the dropdown select the collection name you had created on Watson Explorer Engine, **toggle the searchable button on** in the entity page and once done click on save at the bottom of the page.

- Link (adding backend and entity creation): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8NLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.appbuilder.doc/c_de-ab-devapp-tutorial-integrate.html

Then you may want to head over to the **layouts tab** and then go to the **search page** there, then drag the search results widget to the pane below and save it.

Layout tab - search page, looks like this: [Image Link: Layout tab - search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1phhz.png)

Layout tab - search result widget on search page, looks like this: [Image Link: Search result Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsGwd.png)

Finally after all this, when you search for the document from the search page `"/AppBuilder/search"`, it should show up there.

- Tutorial WEX AppBuilder Resource: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8NLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.appbuilder.doc/c_de-ab-devapp-tutorial.html

Hope this helps.